# How to merge multiple list into a single dataframe replacing common values with 1 -python

Tags: python, phylogenetics, merge, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple lists on python:

```
a = ["house","garden", "living room", "dog","cat"]

b= ["cat","dog", "chicken"]

c=["house", "garden","bathroom"]
```

I'd like to create the following dataframe:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| house | 0 | 1 |
| garden | 0 | 1 |
| living room | 0 | 0 |
| dog | 1 | 0 |
| cat | 1 | 0 |

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi @Marco if you do find the answer below okay (it does work), could you very kindly mark the post as 'accepted'. There's a little grey 'tick' sign to the left of the answer, click that and it goes green. I noted on your past questions you forgotten to do that. Its a small thing but helps everyone, which includes you (you will get +2).

Answer (score 1):

Here  you go, just add column 'C' and you are sorted. Just to note, you must be seeking a `pandas` solution because `merge` is a `pandas` command and you're asking for a `Python` solution.

```
import pandas as pd

a = ["house","garden", "living room", "dog","cat"]
b= ["cat","dog", "chicken"]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns = ['a'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b, columns = ['b'])
dfa = df['a'].value_counts()
dfa.columns = ['a']
dfb = df2['b'].value_counts()
dfb.columns = ['b']
dfa = dfa.to_frame()
dfb = dfb.to_frame()
df3 = dfa.join(dfb).replace(np.nan, 0).astype(int)
print (df3)
```

Output

```
             a  b
house        1  0
garden       1  0
living room  1  0
dog          1  1
cat          1  1
```

and if you want to remove the 'a' column

```
print (df3.drop('a', axis=1))

             b
house        0
garden       0
living room  0
dog          1
cat          1
```

---

**Notes** The key command here is `value_counts` and makes a frequency plot. Its output is a `Series` rather than a `DataFrame` so it needs converting.

If you want to keep all inputs the commands is

```
df3 = pd.concat([dfa, dfb]).replace(np.nan, 0).astype(int)
```

---

Alternatively,

```
a = ["house","garden", "living room", "dog","cat"]
b= ["cat","dog", "chicken"]
df = pd.DataFrame(a).value_counts().to_frame('a')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b).value_counts().to_frame('b')
df3 = df.join(df2).replace(np.nan, 0).astype(int).rename_axis(None)
print (df3.drop('a', axis=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that this asks specifically for a python solution, but I'd like to add an R answer as well, just in case someone using R has a similar problem:

```
> a <- c("house","garden", "living room", "dog","cat")
> b <- c("cat","dog", "chicken")
> c <- c("house", "garden","bathroom")

> (result <- data.frame(row.names=a, a=a %in% a, b=a %in% b, c=a %in% c))
               a     b     c
house       TRUE FALSE  TRUE
garden      TRUE FALSE  TRUE
living room TRUE FALSE FALSE
dog         TRUE  TRUE FALSE
cat         TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

or for strictly what you asked for, the TRUE/FALSE values can be encouraged into numbers by adding zero:

```
> (result <- data.frame(a=a, b=(a %in% b) + 0, c=(a %in% c) + 0))
            a b c
1       house 0 1
2      garden 0 1
3 living room 0 0
4         dog 1 0
5         cat 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Both existing answers seem to work to my eye. An alternative approach:

```
import pandas as pd

a = ["house","garden", "living room", "dog","cat"]
b = ["cat","dog", "chicken"]
c = ["house", "garden","bathroom", "unique"]
```

First we generate all options available. This way your 'a' list is not restricting the options. We use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to get unique values.

```
options = list(set(a + b + c))
wanted = pd.DataFrame({'options' : options} )
```

Next we loop over all the lists. We use [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) to assign both name and variable.

```
for name, _ in [('a',a),('b',b),('c',c)]:
    wanted.loc[wanted['options'].isin(_), name ] = 1
```

Finally we fill the missing values with zeroes.

```
wanted = wanted.fillna('0')
```

In case you have large number of lists, you can iterate over ascii_lowercase letters:

```
my_tuples = ()
from string import ascii_lowercase

for _ in ascii_lowercase[:3]: #<-magic number for number of lists here
     my_tuples = my_tuples + (str(_), eval(_))
```

Then change for loop as:

```
for name, _ in my_tuples:
     ....
```